# Does density of an object affects the difficulty in lifting it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, density

Isn't it that the only thing which affects its lifting difficulty is its mass ? 
For eg:- There is 1Kg of iron and 1Kg of cotton. Is it difficult to lift iron than the cotton due to higher density of iron ? I dont think it is.

Note:- I am asking this question due to the reason that I have read "A very powerful crane is required to lift the nucleus of an atom". Is this statement wrong ?

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Lots of things can affect it. How slippery is it? It is hard to lift a kg of water unless you have a bucket. Red hot iron is harder to lift than room temperature iron. I would have trouble if it was to slimy or smelly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence about the crane and nucleus is nonsense.

Lifting itself is slightly easier for lower density object, as there is higher air buoyancy, that subtracts from the object weight.

But huge difference in density can affect the object manipulation, plus there is the difference in the object moment of  inertia.

E.g turning of a lifted 1000 kg iron object to desired orientation is much easier than turning of a giant 1000 kg  cotton pack. As the latter has a much higher moment if inertia.